# How to create a cron job using Bash automatically without the interactive editor?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

Does `crontab` have an argument for creating cron jobs without using the editor (`crontab -e`)? If so, what would be the code to create a cron job from a Bash script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)

Comment: Sadly, most top answers here are just showing how to modify crontab -- albeit in reasonably safe ways -- but I think it's overall the wrong approach. Better, safer and simpler is to drop a file into {{cron.d}}, and there are (currently) low-vote answers explaining how to do that if you look down further.

Comment: Thanks @gregmac. I added [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069755/1121497) after reading examples from different places and trying it myself.

Comment: @gregmac Using `/etc/cron.daily/` and friends would seem to require superuser privileges.

Answer (score 732, accepted):

You can add to the crontab as follows:

```
#write out current crontab
crontab -l > mycron
#echo new cron into cron file
echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello" >> mycron
#install new cron file
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

---

### Cron line explaination

```
* * * * * "command to be executed"
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

Source [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).

Comment: You should use tempfile or mktemp

Comment: @dogbane i have a doubt. Why "rm mycron" is used here??

Comment: `mycron` is a temporary file used to store the contents of the crontab. You can call it anything you like.

Comment: (crontab -l ; echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello") | crontab -

Comment: `(crontab -l ; echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello") | crontab -` - easier to copy Edo's answear

Comment: I'd suggest to change that `;` with `&&` as a safe-guard against the case if `crontab -l` fails. so, like: `(crontab -l && echo "0 0 0 0 0 some entry") | crontab -`

Comment: In which file is the line writed in with this ? for example for daily task ?

Comment: @Edo, hi, what do i do if i want to make sure no same cronjob are added twice?

Comment: @moeseth I haven't tried (I'm from mobile) but something like this should work `(crontab -l && echo "0 0 0 0 0 some entry" | sort | uniq) | crontab -`

Comment: @MacUsers, `crontab -l` fails if there is no crontab, so using `&&` makes it impossible for the script to add the first entry to the crontab.

Comment: @JPhi1618, that's very true. I took the liberty to think an existing crontab is already there. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Arf, @MacUsers (and others) do you have a suggestion to make this compliant with the first entry of the crontab too?

Comment: Found it but by bypassing the safe guard : `(crontab -l 2>/dev/null ; echo "0 0 0 0 0 some entry") | crontab -`

Comment: This will avoid duplicates: `! (crontab -l | grep -q "SCRIPT_FILENAME") && (crontab -l; echo "20 10 * * * SCRIPT_FILENAME") | crontab -`

Comment: This gives me `no crontab for <username>`

Comment: This won't work if the user has not run `crontab -e` before. This will give `no crontab for <username>`

Answer (score 406):

You may be able to do it on-the-fly

```
crontab -l | { cat; echo "0 0 0 0 0 some entry"; } | crontab -
```

This works since `crontab -l` lists the current crontab jobs, `cat` prints it (from standard input), `echo` prints the new command and `crontab -` adds all the printed stuff into the crontab file. You can see the effect by doing a new `crontab -l`.

Note: if the user has no existing crontab, you may see this message:

```
no crontab for <username>
```

Anyway, it still works, even if you see that message.

Comment: Works a treat for me. If the user has no existing crontab you'll see `no crontab for <username>`, but it works anyway.

Comment: Per the example in the comment above, there's no reason for the cat

Comment: doesn't work on my Amazon EC2 instance. Instead, `(crontab -l ; echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello") | crontab -` works.

Comment: This looks like a candidate for a [UUcatA](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Comment: you may want to pipe through "sort | uniq" before the last command, to avoid duplicating entries in the crontab (this can change the line order though)

Comment: It would be good to add the -u to the example, like here: https://askubuntu.com/a/719877/360354

Comment: Why does `echo -ne "#foo\n$(crontab -l)" | crontab -` not work?

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Fixed: `{ crontab -l; echo "0 0 0 0 0 some entry"; } | crontab -`

Comment: @Stéphane Bruckert, I suspect `{ LIST; }` might be a [tag:bash] thing. In sh-based shells without `{ LIST; }`, one could use `( LIST )` instead as you suggested.

Answer (score 114):

This shorter one requires no temporary file, it is immune to multiple insertions, and it lets you change the schedule of an existing entry.

Say you have these:

```
croncmd="/home/me/myfunction myargs > /home/me/myfunction.log 2>&1"
cronjob="0 */15 * * * $croncmd"
```

To add it to the crontab, with no duplication:

```
( crontab -l | grep -v -F "$croncmd" ; echo "$cronjob" ) | crontab -
```

To remove it from the crontab whatever its current schedule:

```
( crontab -l | grep -v -F "$croncmd" ) | crontab -
```

Notes:

- grep -F matches the string literally, as we do not want to interpret it as a regular expression
- We also ignore the time scheduling and only look for the command. This way; the schedule can be changed without the risk of adding a new line to the crontab

Comment: I cannot understand why your script won't work if crontab is empty. This only happens with non interactive shell on my CI/CD: the same script works fine when run directly from the host (interactive shell).

Comment: This command won't work if your bash script has  `set -e` and crontab list is empty. This happens because `crontab -l | grep -v -F "$croncmd"` exists with`1` therefore stopping immediately the script. To avoid that you can update the line this way `( crontab -l | grep -v -F "$COMMAND" || : ; echo "$JOB" ) | crontab -`. The `|| :` will ensure that `grep` doesn't stop the script if crontab is empty. More on `:` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/1498118).

Comment: Good catch. Indeed, you can also cowardly just issue a `crontab -e` once and foremost in order to make sure it pre-exists ;)

Comment: `croncmd` can be a fragment of the script path that you'd like to use as the duplication blocker. Just build the rest of the command in `cronnjob`.

Answer (score 45):

Thanks everybody for your help. Piecing together what I found here and elsewhere I came up with this:

### The Code

```
command="php $INSTALL/indefero/scripts/gitcron.php"
job="0 0 * * 0 $command"
cat <(fgrep -i -v "$command" <(crontab -l)) <(echo "$job") | crontab -
```

I couldn't figure out how to eliminate the need for the two variables without repeating myself.

`command` is obviously the command I want to schedule. `job` takes `$command` and adds the scheduling data. I needed both variables separately in the line of code that does the work.

### Details

1. Credit to duckyflip, I use this little redirect thingy (`<(*command*)`) to turn the output of `crontab -l` into input for the `fgrep` command.
2. `fgrep` then filters out any matches of `$command` (`-v` option), case-insensitive (`-i` option).
3. Again, the little redirect thingy (`<(*command*)`) is used to turn the result back into input for the `cat` command.
4. The `cat` command also receives `echo "$job"` (self explanatory), again, through use of the redirect thingy (`<(*command*)`).
5. So the filtered output from `crontab -l` and the simple `echo "$job"`, combined, are piped ('|') over to `crontab -` to finally be written.
6. And they all lived happily ever after!

### In a nutshell:

This line of code filters out any cron jobs that match the command, then writes out the remaining cron jobs with the new one, effectively acting like an "add" or "update" function.
To use this, all you have to do is swap out the values for the `command` and `job` variables.

Comment: For the benefit of others reading, the advantage of this approach is that you can run it multiple times without worrying about duplicate entries in the crontab (unlike all the other solutions). That's because of the `fgrep -v`

Comment: If you prefer the traditional left-to-right way of piping things, replace the last line with: 
`crontab -l | fgrep -i -v "$command" | { cat; echo "$job"; } | crontab -l`

Comment: @AntoineLizée, you answer has extra "l" in the end, which shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 33):

EDIT (fixed overwriting):

```
cat <(crontab -l) <(echo "1 2 3 4 5 scripty.sh") | crontab -
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that Bash's process substitution swallows errors. If `crontab -l` fails, but `crontab -` succeeds, your crontab will be a one-liner.

Answer (score 28):

There have been a lot of good answers around the use of crontab, but no mention of a simpler method, such as using `cron`.

Using `cron` would take advantage of system files and directories located at `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.daily,weekly,hourly` or `/etc/cron.d/`:

```
cat > /etc/cron.d/<job> << EOF
SHELL=/bin/bash 
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin 
MAILTO=root HOME=/  
01 * * * * <user> <command>
EOF
```

In this above example, we created a file in `/etc/cron.d/`, provided the environment variables for the command to execute successfully, and provided the `user` for the command, and the `command` itself. This file should not be executable and the name should only contain alpha-numeric and hyphens (more details below).

To give a thorough answer though, let's look at the differences between `crontab` vs `cron/crond`:

```
crontab -- maintain tables for driving cron for individual users
```

For those who want to run the job in the context of their user on the system, using `crontab` may make perfect sense.

```
cron -- daemon to execute scheduled commands
```

For those who use configuration management or want to manage jobs for other users, in which case we should use `cron`.

A quick excerpt from the manpages gives you a few examples of what to and not to do:

> /etc/crontab and the files in /etc/cron.d must be owned  by  root,  and must  not  be  group- or other-writable. In contrast to the spool area, the files  under  /etc/cron.d  or  the  files  under  /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily,  /etc/cron.weekly  and  /etc/cron.monthly  may also be symlinks, provided that both the symlink and the file it points to  are owned  by  root.   The  files  under  /etc/cron.d  do  not  need  to be executable, while the files  under  /etc/cron.hourly,  /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly and /etc/cron.monthly do, as they are run by run-parts (see run-parts(8) for more information).
>
> **Source:** http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/cron.8.html

Managing crons in this manner is easier and more scalable from a system perspective, but will not always be the best solution.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `<job>` should not include a file extension.

Comment: This would seem to require superuser privileges.  Is there a non-super-user equivalent?

Answer (score 11):

So, in Debian, Ubuntu, and many similar Debian based distros...

There is a cron task concatenation mechanism that takes a config file, bundles them up and adds them to your cron service running.

You can put a file under the /etc/cron.d/somefilename where somefilename is whatever you want.

```
sudo echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * ntpdate -u time.nist.gov" >> /etc/cron.d/vmclocksync
```

Let's disassemble this:

sudo - because you need elevated privileges to change cron configs under the /etc directory

echo - a vehicle to create output on std out. printf, cat... would work as well

" - use a doublequote at the beginning of your string, you're a professional

0,15,30,45 * * * * - the standard cron run schedule, this one runs every 15 minutes

ntpdate -u time.nist.gov - the actual command I want to run

" - because my first double quotes needs a buddy to close the line being output

>> - the double redirect appends instead of overwrites*

/etc/cron.d/vmclocksync - vmclocksync is the filename I've chosen, it goes in /etc/cron.d/

---

* if we used the > redirect, we could guarantee we only had one task entry. But, we would be at risk of blowing away any other rules in an existing file. You can decide for yourself if possible destruction with > is right or possible duplicates with >> are for you. Alternatively, you could do something convoluted or involved to check if the file name exists, if there is anything in it, and whether you are adding any kind of duplicate-- but, I have stuff to do and I can't do that for you right now.

Comment: I had a long running VM where the host OS would go to sleep-- the time wasn't critical on the VM, but it would start to get really out of whack to where it wasn't even the right day anymore.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, `sudo` doesn't affect redirects. See [SC2024](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2024) and the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56283541/1121497

Comment: Isn't the user after cron schedule mandatory for this to work ?
I got " cron[650]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/cron.d/vmclocksync " 
when checking cron with " systemctl status cron "

Answer (score 8):

Chances are you are automating this, and you don't want a single job added twice.
In that case use:

```
__cron="1 2 3 4 5 /root/bin/backup.sh"
cat <(crontab -l) |grep -v "${__cron}" <(echo "${__cron}")
```

This only works if you're using BASH. I'm not aware of the correct DASH (`sh`) syntax.

**Update:** This doesn't work if the user doesn't have a crontab yet. A more reliable way would be:

```
(crontab -l ; echo "1 2 3 4 5 /root/bin/backup.sh") | sort - | uniq - | crontab -
```

Alternatively, if your distro supports it, you could also use a separate file:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5 /root/bin/backup.sh" |sudo tee /etc/crond.d/backup
```

Found those in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job).

Comment: Using sh instead of bash maybe?

Comment: Still getting `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` using *sh*.

Comment: This only works if you're using BASH. I'm not aware of the correct DASH (sh) syntax. Updated the answer as well

Comment: fwiw, I get this error using bash if there is a space between the `<` and `(`. That means `< (` fails but `<(` works, unless there are asterisks in your schedule...

Comment: I believe this is the correct way:
`cat <(crontab -l |grep -v "${CRON}") <(echo "${CRON}") | crontab -`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the syntax

Answer (score 8):

For a nice quick and dirty creation/replacement of a crontab from with a BASH script, I used this notation:

```
crontab <<EOF
00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "0 * * * * docker system prune --force >/dev/null 2>&1" | sudo tee /etc/cron.daily/dockerprune
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll just add that there is also `/etc/cron.d` for general crons. I guess that `/etc/cron.daily` is just for daily crons.

Answer (score 5):

A variant which only edits crontab if the desired string is not found there:

```
CMD="/sbin/modprobe fcpci"
JOB="@reboot $CMD"
TMPC="mycron"
grep "$CMD" -q <(crontab -l) || (crontab -l>"$TMPC"; echo "$JOB">>"$TMPC"; crontab "$TMPC")
```

Answer (score 5):

1. 

```
(2>/dev/null crontab -l ; echo "0 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew") | crontab -
```

2. 

```
cat <(crontab -l 2>/dev/null) <(echo "0 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew") | crontab -
```

3. 

#write out current crontab

```
crontab -l > mycron 2>/dev/null
```

#echo new cron into cron file

```
echo "0 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew" >> mycron
```

#install new cron file

```
crontab mycron

rm mycron
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Vixie Cron, e.g. on most Linux distributions, you can just put a file in /etc/cron.d with the individual cronjob.

This only works for root of course. If your system supports this you should see several examples in there. (Note the username included in the line, in the same syntax as the old /etc/crontab)

It's a sad misfeature in cron that there is no way to handle this as a regular user, and that so many cron implementations have no way at all to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Bash script for adding cron job without the interactive editor.
Below code helps to add a cronjob using linux files.

```
#!/bin/bash

cron_path=/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

#cron job to run every 10 min.
echo "*/10 * * * * command to be executed" >> $cron_path

#cron job to run every 1 hour.
echo "0 */1 * * * command to be executed" >> $cron_path
```

Comment: I know it's been a loooong time, but this is still the only fine answer, since all the most voted ones remove the old crons instead of just append the new one.

Comment: This one doesn't install a cron. It just appends it to a file. You will have to somehow notify cron process to install the new entry.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred solution to this would be this:

```
(crontab -l | grep . ; echo -e "0 4 * * * myscript\n") | crontab -
```

This will make sure you are handling the blank new line at the bottom correctly. To avoid issues with crontab you should usually end the crontab file with a blank new line. And the script above makes sure it first removes any blank lines with the "grep ." part, and then add in a new blank line at the end with the "\n" in the end of the script. This will also prevent getting a blank line above your new command if your existing crontab file ends with a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash function for adding a command to `crontab` without duplication

```
function addtocrontab () {
  local frequency=$1
  local command=$2
  local job="$frequency $command"
  cat <(fgrep -i -v "$command" <(crontab -l)) <(echo "$job") | crontab -
}
addtocrontab "0 0 1 * *" "echo hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CRON="1 2 3 4 5 /root/bin/backup.sh" 
cat < (crontab -l) |grep -v "${CRON}" < (echo "${CRON}")
```

add -w parameter to grep exact command, without -w parameter adding the cronjob "testing" cause deletion of cron job "testing123"

script function to add/remove cronjobs. no duplication entries :

```
cronjob_editor () {         
# usage: cronjob_editor '<interval>' '<command>' <add|remove>

if [[ -z "$1" ]] ;then printf " no interval specified\n" ;fi
if [[ -z "$2" ]] ;then printf " no command specified\n" ;fi
if [[ -z "$3" ]] ;then printf " no action specified\n" ;fi

if [[ "$3" == add ]] ;then
    # add cronjob, no duplication:
    ( crontab -l | grep -v -F -w "$2" ; echo "$1 $2" ) | crontab -
elif [[ "$3" == remove ]] ;then
    # remove cronjob:
    ( crontab -l | grep -v -F -w "$2" ) | crontab -
fi 
} 
cronjob_editor "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

tested :

```
$ ./cronjob_editor.sh '*/10 * * * *' 'echo "this is a test" > export_file' add
$ crontab  -l
$ */10 * * * * echo "this is a test" > export_file
```

Comment: If you have the same command in the crontab twice (running at different times) the remove will delete both lines.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option in crontab to modify the cron files.

You have to: take the current cron file (crontab -l > newfile), change it and put the new file in place (crontab newfile).

If you are familiar with perl, you can use this module [Config::Crontab](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-Crontab/Crontab.pm).

LLP, Andrea

Answer (score 0):

script function to add cronjobs. check duplicate entries,useable expressions * > "

```
cronjob_creator () {         
# usage: cronjob_creator '<interval>' '<command>'

  if [[ -z $1 ]] ;then
    printf " no interval specified\n"
elif [[ -z $2 ]] ;then
    printf " no command specified\n"
else
    CRONIN="/tmp/cti_tmp"
    crontab -l | grep -vw "$1 $2" > "$CRONIN"
    echo "$1 $2" >> $CRONIN
    crontab "$CRONIN"
    rm $CRONIN
fi
}
```

tested :

```
$ ./cronjob_creator.sh '*/10 * * * *' 'echo "this is a test" > export_file'
$ crontab  -l
$ */10 * * * * echo "this is a test" > export_file
```

source : my brain ;)

Answer (score 0):

Say you're logged in as the user "ubuntu", but you want to add a job to a different user's crontab, like "john", for example. You can do the following:

```
(sudo crontab -l -u john; echo "* * * * * command") | awk '!x[$0]++' | sudo crontab -u john -
```

Source for most of this solution: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/create-crontab-script

I was having tons of issues trying to add a job to **another user's crontab**. It kept duplicating crontabs, or just flat-out deleting them. After some testing, though, I'm confident this line of code will **append** a new job to a specified user's crontab, non-destructively, including not creating a job that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find an example like this, so maybe it helps:

```
COMMAND="/var/lib/postgresql/backup.sh"
CRON="0 0 * * *"
USER="postgres"
CRON_FILE="postgres-backup"
# At CRON times, the USER will run the COMMAND
echo "$CRON $USER $COMMAND" | sudo tee /etc/cron.d/$CRON_FILE
echo "Cron job created. Remove /etc/cron.d/$CRON_FILE to stop it."
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward, add your scripts in `/etc/crontab`.
I want to restart some pipeline `daily at 4 AM`, So I had created one bash script `daily_restart.sh`

```
#daily_restart.sh

docker-compose -f /mnt/ssd/workspace/facesense_final_release_2023/client_release_edge/docker-compose-facesense-050523.yml down
docker-compose -f /mnt/ssd/workspace/facesense_final_release_2023/client_release_edge/docker-compose-facesense-050523.yml up -d
```

I have added this script in `/etc/crontab`

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
* 4 * * * root /home/mic-710ail/restart.sh
#
```

my cronjob is `* 4 * * * root /home/mic-710ail/restart.sh`
this job will run daily 4 AM

for more cronjob examples follow [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/)