# Create CronJob Using Bash Script - Need To Appear In Plesk

Tags: cron, plesk

I need to create a cron job using a bash script
I found this on SO - [How to create a cron job using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878600/how-to-create-cronjob-using-bash)

But i need it to appear in Plesk control panel in Scheduled Tasks.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Plesk panel use a database called PSA.
I do not have any plesk installation at the moment!

I suggest you connect to mysql psa database and look for the cron table (usually, the table name is self explanatory), you create a false cron trough plesk to see the changes made on that database,and you add yours!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using crontab like the example you are using, create your script and add it to your scheduled items in the plesk GUI. 
Here is a nice little video tutorial to walk you through the task scheduling aspect of it.
http://fastdot.co.uk/tutorials/plesk-windows-hosting/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-scheduled-tasks-in-plesk.html