# Scheduling php script?

Tags: php

I was looking for a php script that will get executed **every hour** ( without executing it ) ( ex. for sending emails ) but i don't know, the way it works. Do i have to use Cron Jobs or is there anything in php to make such kind of scripts?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP does not have anything like this included. You have to use an external tool, such as [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878600/how-to-create-cronjob-using-bash), to run a PHP script perdiodically.

If you are not allowed to set cron jobs on your web hosting, there exist websites that will call one URL periodically, like http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/.

Comment: Ohh.. I saw IPB Forums using something ( don't know what ) for generating RSS every mentioned minutes. So do they install Cron jobs thr' php scripts?

Comment: You can also use what is known as Poor mans cron (like Poormanscron in drupal) or PMC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cron jobs if you want it to run on a set schedule.

Comment: Thank you, but installing cron jobs manually is.. or i can do something with php script to install that cron job for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using linux, go to the terminal and type crontab -e.

Your line will be something like that

```
1  2 3 4 5 (this line here is just an information.. dont type it on crontab)
00 * * * * wget www.page.com/yourphp.php
```

So the script will run
1  00  On minute 00
2  *   Every hour
3  *   Every day
4  *   Every month
5  *   Every day of the week

Then type :wq to close
So its done.

You need to have the crontab and the wget in this scenario.