# Bash Variable at execution time

Tags: cron, bash

There is bash script to setup a cron job .

start.sh :

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the log directory: " -i "/home/arya/apps/" LOGPATH
read -e -p "Enter comma separated recepient email-ids:" EMAIL

CURRENT=`pwd` 
COMMAND="python ${CURRENT}/start.sh 2014-08-01T21:12:12 2014-08-01T23:12:12 $LOGPATH  $EMAIL" 
echo $COMMAND   #Here expected output is coming :  */3+1 * * * *  python /home/arya/start.sh 2014-08-01T21:12:12 2014-08-01T23:12:12 /home/arya/apps/utils anilarya280@gmail.com 
cat <(fgrep -i -v "$COMMAND" <(crontab -l)) <(echo "*/3+1 * * * *") | crontab -
```

This is not taking $CURRENT value in crontab file. Ouput on looking file using crontab -e command:

```
*/3+1 * * * *         rest things are missing.
```

Expected output :

```
  */3+1 * * * *  python /home/arya/start.sh 2014-08-01T21:12:12 2014-08-01T23:12:12 /home/arya/apps/utils anilarya280@gmail.com
```

What is problem here?

PLATFORM : UBUNTU 13.04

Comment: According to your output, it appears to be missing the entire `COMMAND` not just `CURRENT`. My initial speculation is that the output of the `fgrep` is coming out blank or null, so you're just getting the output of `echo`. You can break it down and check each piece first. Try running the `fgrep -i -v "$COMMAND" <(crontab -l)` command by itself, after setting the shell variables `CURRENT` and `COMMAND` and see if it gives you what you expect.

Comment: [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: But echo $COMMAND is giving complete thing.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to just add a command to your cron tab, there are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878600/how-to-create-cronjob-using-bash) [answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58575/add-lines-to-cron-from-script).

Comment: Its not able to put COMMAND variable in crontab file.

Comment: A command group `{ fgrep ...; echo ...; } | crontab -` is much simpler than using `cat` with process substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the COMMAND variable in the echo to display it.

```
cat <(fgrep -i -v "$COMMAND" <(crontab -l)) <(echo "*/3+1 * * * * $COMMAND") | crontab -
```