# Scheduled Tasks using SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

How do you schedule tasks to run in SilverStripe, for example run a task every hour? Or even access a rest api every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities: Cron or... faked cron.

If you can [use cron on your server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/878647/4137738) directly [call SilverStripe in your CLI](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/cli/#running-regular-tasks-with-cron).

```
//run a task "MyTask" every hour at minute 29:

//min hr day month dayofweek 
29 * * * * /your/site/folder/sake dev/tasks/MyTask

//run a task "MyTask" at 3:13 am every sunday:

29 3 * * 0 /your/site/folder/sake dev/tasks/MyTask
```

If you do not have access to cron for some reason, there is this [SilverStripe crontask module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-crontask) you can use.