# Date is getting Printed in echo command while executing shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Hope everyone is having a good day 
i'm trying to write a script to introduce a cron job via script
the following command is working fine when executed in shell script

```
echo '0 20 * * * touch /global/appaem/aem/wrap-lock/wrap.lock-`date +"%Y%m%d"`' >> /tmp/tmp.txt
more /tmp/tmp.txt 
0 20 * * * touch /global/appaem/aem/wrap-lock/wrap.lock-`date +"%Y%m%d"
```

But when the same command is being executed from script it's displaying the below o/p

```
/global/appaem/aem/wrap-lock/wrap.lock-20170707
```

can some help here

Comment: With what? You have touched a file called global/appaem/aem/wrap-lock/wrap.lock-20170707? With 20170707 derived from the date command.

Comment: Consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/878647)

Comment: So, your commands work fine for me in bash, sh, and when plugged directly into terminal. What OS are you running? Possibly try escaping your ` ` ` (grave accent) like so ` \\` `.

Comment: @KipK yes it does work in normal shell when u type , but it doesn't when you execute it through shell script , because shell is interpreting and execute date command in echo , Eduard has provided the solution. we should use escape character to make sure shell doesn't interpret it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should prefer `$()` in `bash` to fork a subshell.

To print out your desired command without being interpreted by `bash`, you need to escape `$`, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "0 20 * * * touch /global/appaem/aem/wrap-lock/wrap.lock-\$(date +\"%Y%m%d\")" >> /tmp/tmp.txt
```