# How do I create a crontab through a script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

I need to add a cron job thru a script I run to set up a server. I am currently using Ubuntu. I can use `crontab -e` but that will open an editor to edit the current crontab. I want to do this programmatically.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)

Comment: If you're looking to modify or delete a crontab entry, see my solution below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cron jobs usually are stored in a per-user file under `/var/spool/cron`

The simplest thing for you to do is probably just create a text file with the job configured, then copy it to the cron spool folder and make sure it has the right permissions (600).

Comment: Modifying the files directly in /var/spool/cron is frowned upon. In fact, if you look at the files there, they will usually contain warnings such as "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE" as the first line.

Comment: @Jared While I quite agree with the idea, saying it "is frowned upon" doesn't help much.  Rather tell which _other_ file should be edited, if any, or explain the risks of editing files manually.
I'm planning to create some cron jobs via automated command line, and if editing this file is both the only option, and without significant side effects, I don't see why I shouldn't use it.

Comment: Scroll down for the real answer.

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is way better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/610860/2681752

Comment: I took this approach and regretted it. On RHEL, the directory /var/spool/cron is not world executable, so users can't traverse the directory and edit their files manually. If you make /var/spool/cron world executable, your friendly local sysadmin will be mad at you, plus the permission change can be overwritten if the cronie package is ever reinstalled or updated.

Comment: @Jared those warnings are often because there is something like cpanel or plesk on the server, and these may overwrite the cron file(s) at some point. Appreciate that you may have learned that in the last 4 years!

Answer (score 539):

Here's a one-liner that doesn't use/require the new job to be in a file:

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * /path/to/job -with args") | crontab -
```

The `2>/dev/null` is important so that you don't get the `no crontab for username` message that some *nixes produce if there are currently no crontab entries.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Just need a way now to check if the one-liner I intend to add is already there or not...

Comment: ...oh wait, here's how to check if something is in my user's crontab before I add it with a script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14451184/3686125

Comment: if this script is intended as a command to be repeated and modify an existing cron task, it could be nice to replace the existing line in crontab. several markers can be used to control different cron tasks (control-marker-1, control-marker-2, etc...):      
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null | grep -v control-marker-1; echo '*/5 * * * * /path/to/job -with args #control-marker-1') | crontab -

Comment: I found that this was removing existing crontab entries and also I needed to use a different user (root) so I used the following to maintain the existing entries:
`echo -e "$(sudo crontab -u root -l)\n* * * * * echo hello > /home/danny/temp.log 2>&1" | sudo crontab -u root -`
Hopefully this helps someone

Comment: What does `*/` mean here?

Comment: @SOFe - it's a step value, meaning that you take all of the allowable values ("*") and run the command on any that are evenly divisible by whatever the value is ("/5"). So this would run the command every minute that is evenly divisible by 5 (i.e. 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55). If I had done "10-38" it would run @ minutes 16, 24, and 32. See 'man 5 crontab' for more examples.

Comment: I see, thanks. It's strange how come everyone uses that in this page when it's not related to the OP.

Comment: On debian, I had not to add the trailing dash for this to work. Pipe says to branch the previous command stdout to stdin.

Comment: I have tried this method but get the following error when running the script:
_"-":23: bad command_
My script contain the following:
`#!\bin\bash
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "sleep 60 && @reboot /root/a/myscript") | crontab -`

Comment: @LEyahoo -- that error is coming from cron itself; you need some kind of time specifier as the first element, e.g. `echo "@reboot sleep 60 && /root/a/myscript"`. I think the sleep would best be done inside of `myscript`, though, making the crontab entry that much simpler.

Comment: +1 This solution is exactly what I need. However it will be good if an explanation could be given on how `2>/dev/null` works.

Comment: @user3437460 - that is Bash's I/O redirection at work; it takes anything printed to STDERR (file descriptor #2) and redirects it to the "file" `/dev/null`, which is a special device that (essentially) ignores anything written to it. See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html for more info.

Comment: Make sure to so see this below https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497394/699493 if you use if you use "set -e":  because this will silently fail in a confusing way. Thanks @Faria!

Answer (score 72):

For user crontabs (including root), you can do something like:

```
crontab -l -u user | cat - filename | crontab -u user -
```

where the file named "filename" contains items to append. You could also do text manipulation using `sed` or another tool in place of `cat`. You should use the `crontab` command instead of directly modifying the file.

A similar operation would be:

```
{ crontab -l -u user; echo 'crontab spec'; } | crontab -u user -
```

If you are modifying or creating system crontabs, those may be manipulated as you would ordinary text files. They are stored in the `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, `/etc/cron.monthly` directories and in the files `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/anacrontab`.

Comment: Looked promising but trying the second approach (with `echo`), I got "crontab: usage error: file name must be specified for replace." Cron man page shows syntax as `crontab [ -u user ] file`, that is, with a mandatory file name.  Is there some trick to get it to accept the piped data instead?

Comment: @MarkBerry: Sorry about that. In a pipe, a hyphen must be used to indicate that input is from `stdin`. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 42):

In Ubuntu and many other distros, you can just put a file into the `/etc/cron.d` directory containing a single line with a valid [crontab](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) entry. No need to add a line to an existing file.

If you just need something to run daily, just put a file into `/etc/cron.daily`. Likewise, you can also drop files into `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.monthly`, and `/etc/cron.weekly`.

Comment: But you must be root to do this.

Comment: @IvanGoneKrazy - Any such folder if I have to run at every reboot?

Answer (score 36):

[Joe Casadonte's one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881694/10127517) is perfect, except if you run with `set -e`, i.e. if your script is set to fail on error, and if there are no cronjobs yet. In that case, the one-liner will NOT create the cronjob, but will NOT stop the script. The silent failure can be very misleading.

The reason is that `crontab -l` returns with a `1` return code, causing the subsequent command (the `echo`) not to be executed... thus the cronjob is not created. But since they are executed as a subprocess (because of the parenthesis) they don't stop the script.

(Interestingly, if you run the same command again, it will work: once you have executed `crontab -` once, `crontab -l` still outputs nothing, but it doesn't return an error anymore (you don't get the `no crontab for <user>` message anymore). So the subsequent `echo` is executed and the crontab is created)

In any case, if you run with `set -e`, the line must be:

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null || true; echo "*/5 * * * * /path/to/job -with args") | crontab -
```

Comment: Yes, this one's even more perfect.

Comment: Good one - I hope it gave you the missing reputation!

Comment: The only useful answer I found for this problem.

Answer (score 24):

Crontab files are simply text files and as such can be treated like any other text file.  The purpose of the `crontab` command is to make editing crontab files safer.  When edited through this command, the file is checked for errors and only saved if there are none.

`crontab [path to file]` can be used to specify a crontab stored in a file.  Like `crontab -e`, this will only install the file if it is error free.

Therefore, a script can either directly write cron tab files, or write them to a temporary file and load them with the `crontab [path to temp file]` command.  Writing directly saves having to write a temporary file, but it also avoids the safety check.

Comment: For noobs such as myself, note that it is `crontab [path to file]` .. This was definately the best option for me, as it allows more legible code. I use crontab to track parcels and change my desktop wallpaper with the status. When I'm not expecting parcels, it doesn't need to check every hour. That's why I wanted the script to auto-edit the cron frequency.

Comment: @Rasmus That sounds like an awesome script I'd love to be able to steal. Any chance of sharing via a gist or similar?

Comment: Just FYI that `crontab [path to file]` doesn't necessarily need a "temporary" file, it can load any file that is properly formatted in a crontab layout. This is the approach we are using with SlickStack, so that the crontab template can be updated (downloaded) anytime and then reinstalled: https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/00-crontab.txt

Answer (score 21):

Even more simple answer to you question would be:

```
echo "0 1 * * * /root/test.sh" | tee -a /var/spool/cron/root
```

You can setup cronjobs on remote servers as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
servers="srv1 srv2 srv3 srv4 srv5"
for i in $servers
  do
  echo "0 1 * * * /root/test.sh" | ssh $i " tee -a /var/spool/cron/root"
done
```

In Linux, the default location of the `crontab` file is `/var/spool/cron/`. Here you can find the `crontab` files of all users. You just need to append your cronjob entry to the respective user's file. In the above example, the root user's crontab file is getting appended with a cronjob to run `/root/test.sh` every day at 1 AM.

Comment: That would be `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

As a correction to those suggesting `crontab -l | crontab -`: This does not work on every system. For example, I had to add a job to the root crontab on dozens of servers running an old version SUSE (don't ask why). Old SUSEs prepend comment lines to the output of `crontab -l`, making `crontab -l | crontab -` non-idempotent (Debian recognizes this problem in the crontab manpage and patched its version of Vixie Cron to change the default behaviour of `crontab -l`).

To edit crontabs programmatically on systems where `crontab -l` adds comments, you can try the following:

`EDITOR=cat crontab -e > old_crontab; cat old_crontab new_job | crontab -`

`EDITOR=cat` tells crontab to use `cat` as an editor (not the usual default vi), which doesn't change the file, but instead copies it to stdout. This might still fail if `crontab -` expects input in a format different from what `crontab -e` outputs. Do not try to replace the final `crontab -` with `crontab -e` - it will not work.

Answer (score 6):

Well `/etc/crontab` just an ascii file so the simplest is to just

```
 echo "*/15 * * * *   root     date" >> /etc/crontab
```

which will add a job which will email you every 15 mins.  Adjust to taste, and test via `grep` or other means whether the line was already added to make your script idempotent.

On Ubuntu et al, you can also drop files in `/etc/cron.*` which is easier to do and test for---plus you don't mess with (system) config files such as `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: I think that technically crond is not required to monitor changes to crontab, even if in reality most implementations do, so I'd recommend a call to crontab -e afterwards to prod it. crontab -e honours the EDITOR variable if memory serves, so setting it to /bin/true for the moment should just force the crontab to be re-read.

Comment: True yet on any recent Linux system `crond` *does* monitor, and it certainly does on the OP's stated platform.

Comment: Only if you're root and want the script to run as root. That might not be desirable in the OPs case.

Comment: Not so, I have plenty of non-root entries in /etc/crontab.  You 'merely' need sudo to append to the file.   Anyway, as I stated, there is also /etc/cron.*/ but you also need to be root to write there.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to modify cron a entry without directly editing the cron file (which is frowned upon).

```
crontab -l -u <user> | sed 's/find/replace/g' | crontab -u <user> -
```

If you want to remove a cron entry, use this:

```
crontab -l -u <user> | sed '/find/d' | crontab -u <user> -
```

I realize this is not what gaurav was asking for, but why not have all the solutions in one place?

Comment: Can you give a fully working example that actually replaces a cron expression? I tried, but it's not working for me. Especially when the scheduled script's full path is used with forwards slashes.

Comment: @Koder101 maybe have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005 for what and how you need to escape when using `sed`

Answer (score 3):

It is an approach to incrementally add the cron job:

```
  ssh USER_NAME@$PRODUCT_IP nohup "echo '*/2 * * * * ping -c2 PRODUCT_NAME.com >> /var/www/html/test.html' | crontab -u USER_NAME -"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to add multiple scripts to crontab at once:

```
cat <<EOF | crontab -
* * * * * /bin/foo.sh
* * * * * /bin/gaga.sh
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a crontab deploy tool in python: https://github.com/monklof/deploycron

```
pip install deploycron
```

Install your crontab is very easy, this will merge the crontab into the system's existing crontab.

```
from deploycron import deploycron
deploycron(content="* * * * * echo hello > /tmp/hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

This would insert the cron jobs listed in `my-cron-jobs.txt` into the crontab, while avoiding creating duplicate entries:

```
( (crontab -l 2>/dev/null || true; cat my-cron-jobs.txt) | sort -u) | crontab -
```

More specifically, `sort -u` **sorts all entries in the crontab** and **removes any duplicate lines** (including duplicate empty lines).

So this has the (possibly unwanted/wanted) side effect of removing any already existing duplicate lines in the crontab, and sorting the entries.

It builds upon previous answers by [Faria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497394/930640), [Joe Casadonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625233/930640) and [this answer from the Unix & Linux Stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457334/448229).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to use echo with >> and then run crontab filename
ex:

```
 ssh $HOST "echo \"* * * * * echo hello >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root\"; sleep 2; crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply `crontab -l < "your-file-path"`