# Insert entry into crontab unless it already exists (as one-liner if possible)

Tags: bash, centos6

What's the preferred method to insert an entry into /etc/crontab unless it exists, preferably using a one-liner?

Here's my example entry I wish to place into /etc/crontab unless it already exists in there.

```
*/1 *  *  *  * some_user python /mount/share/script.py
```

I'm on CentOS 6.6 and so far I have this:

```
if grep "*/1 *  *  *  * some_user python /mount/share/script.py" /etc/crontab; then echo "Entry already in crontab"; else echo "*/1 *  *  *  * some_user python /mount/share/script.py" >> /etc/crontab; fi
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this:

```
grep 'some_user python /mount/share/script.py' /etc/crontab || echo '*/1 *  *  *  * some_user python /mount/share/script.py' >> /etc/crontab
```

If the line is absent, `grep` will return `1`, so the right hand side of the or `||` will be executed.

Comment: I understand that we are not supposed to edit /etc/crontab directly these days - how would we do it with crontab -e?

Comment: (crontab -l | grep 'some_user python /mount/share/script.py') || { crontab -l; '*/1 *  *  *  * some_user python /mount/share/script.py'; } | crontab -

Comment: @PhilJ why we use crontab -l before '*/1 * * * *....' ?

Comment: Does not work for me: "Permission denied". Going to explore options with `tee`

Comment: @PhilJ Getting an error `-bash: */1 * * * * some_user python /mount/share/script.py: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Estet  We use that to get the existing cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if grep "\*\/5 \* \* \* \* /usr/local/bin/test.sh" /var/spool/cron/root; then echo "Entry already in crontab"; else echo "*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/test.sh" >>  /var/spool/cron/root; fi
```

Or even more terse:

```
grep '\*\/12 \* \* \* \* /bin/yum makecache fast' /var/spool/cron/root \
    || echo '*/12 * * * * /bin/yum makecache fast' >> /var/spool/cron/root
```

Comment: You should not write to /var/spool/cron/root directly, it is specifically stated in the documentation, you have to go through crontab. The files in /var/spool/cron must include only properly formatted lines, which crontab checks before committing to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Factoring out the filename & using the q & F options

`file="/etc/crontab"; grep -qF "some_user python /mount/share/script.py" "$file" || echo "*/1 *  *  *  * some_user python /mount/share/script.py"`