# How to set Cron Job using phpseclib?

Tags: php, bash, cron, phpseclib

```
        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'C:\wamp\www\Web Apps\backend\phpsec');
        include ('phpsec/Net/SSH2.php');
        $ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.example.com');
        if (!($ssh->login('userlogin', 'password'))) {
            exit('Login Failed');
        }

        echo "Login Success<br>";


        $output=$ssh->exec('crontab -e;30 17 * * 1 /path/to/command')

        echo "$output";
```

Here I am trying to set cron job. But it gives following error "**Error opening terminal: unknown. /usr/bin/crontab.cagefs: "pico" exited with status 1 bash: 30: command not found**" So how to set cron job using phpseclib?

Comment: That does sound like a problem on the server you are connecting to. Can you execute the line to edit the cronjob there without problems?

Comment: I can delete the cron job there but I cannot add. @NicoHaase

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625233/569976 . You might need a PTY to do some of that stuff idk

Comment: Try `crontab -l | { cat; echo -e "30 17 * * 1 /path/to/command"; } | crontab -` no need to open cron

Comment: @JesilDesouza the other comments should help you find a solution - this is not a problem based on PHP or phpseclib, but on a wrongly executed shell command

Comment: @NicoHaase what should be the shell command

Comment: The part you are putting into $ssh->exec() is the shell command to be executed, that's what this command is for ;) If this is completely new to you, I would strongly advise not to work on this script anymore, as you can screw up a lot with this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following command in exec() function

```
  $ssh->exec('crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * /path/to/command/"; } | crontab -');
```