# "Syntax error near unexpected token `crontab'" when trying to add cron job in one line as sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-ec2, cron

I am getting a "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `crontab'" when I am attempting to write a cron job to crontab in one line. (This is for a launch configuration on EC2.) [I am following this guide here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625233/4794211)

This is my command:

```
sudo { crontab -l -u ec2-user; echo "* * * * * touch /home/ec2-user/dummy/dummy$ENV"; } | crontab -u ec2-user -
```

If I run without sudo, it tells me I "must be privileged to use -u." When I run with sudo I get "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'"

I am sure I have my syntax wrong with the sudo, but I am not sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to accomplish what you want:

```
sudo bash -c "{ crontab -l -u ec2-user; echo '* * * * * touch /home/ec2-user/dummy/dummy$ENV'; } | crontab -u ec2-user -"
```

This way, you only have to specify `sudo` once.

Comment: So this works, but its not grabbing the value for $ENV. Any idea why?

Comment: @Brandon: Try swapping the single and double quotes and let me know if that works.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon: I updated my answer to reflect your results. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` can only run external commands, not shell syntax like brace groups (or loops/functions/if-statements/etc). Use it on the individual commands you need special privileges for:

```
{ sudo crontab -l -u ec2-user; echo "* * * * * touch /home/ec2-user/dummy/dummy$ENV"; } | sudo crontab -u ec2-user -
```