# Appending to crontab with a shell script on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, cron

I'm trying to add a line to the crontab on Ubuntu.

Right now, I'm doing `crontab -e` and editing the crontab there.

However, I can't seem to find the real crontab file, since `crontab -e` seems to give you a temporary working copy.

`/etc/crontab` looks like the system crontab.

What is the path of the crontab that `crontab -e` saves to?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `crontab -l > file` to list current user's crontab to the `file`, and `crontab file`, to install new crontab.

Comment: For example, this one liner will add a job that runs script.sh on every reboot: `crontab -l > file; echo "@reboot /home/user/script.sh" >> file; crontab file; rm file`

Answer (score 165):

You can also do it without a temporary file:

```
(crontab -l ; echo "0 4 * * * myscript")| crontab -
```

Comment: wish i had looked at this one first.  nice.

Comment: What does `crontab -` mean?

Comment: `crontab -` means replace crontab with standard input.

Comment: Should be `(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "0 4 * * * myscript")| crontab -` as otherwise `no crontab for $user` might be written to the output if no crontab was already present

Comment: @LuGo that's not true, the no crontab message is stderr and crontab - writes stdin from the pipe. However, `(crontab -l || true; echo "0 4 * * * myscript")| crontab -` is necessary if `set -e` is in place since the subshell will error on a nonexistent crontab and silently not write the echo part.

Answer (score 20):

If your crontab is empty you should use `2>/dev/null`:

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "0 4 * * * myscript")| crontab -
```

Comment: Take it with caution because doing it this way `2>/dev/null` may not let you know of any other errors, I would personally rather to see an error once than to skip all the errors forever

Comment: @Ordiel Are there really any other errors you could get from `crontab -l`?

Comment: In typical shell behavior, the pipe already omits stderr: so without touching stderr, the error msg should still not end up in the crontab. E.g, if you *wanted* stderr in the pipe, in Bash you would add an '&' after the pipe: |&

Comment: This is unnecessary. Crontab will not append the stderr empty message to the crontab if it's empty.

Comment: Or for `sh` or C shells: `( ( crontab -l ; echo "0 4 * * * myscript" ) | crontab - ) >& /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

The user crontab file is in '/var/spool/cron/crontabs' for ubuntu.

```
adyliu@adyliu-pc:~$ sudo ls -lh /var/spool/cron/crontabs/adyliu
-rw------- 1 adyliu crontab 1.2K 2012-03-01 09:33 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/adyliu
```

'adyliu' is your login user.

You need root privilege to see this file.

Using "crontab -e" maybe is the best way to modify cron script.

In the manual:

***Users are not allowed to edit the files under that directory directly
to ensure that only users allowed by the system to run periodic tasks
can add them, and only syntactically  correct  crontabs will be
written there.***