# Run two commands with a crontab

Tags: shell, cron, debian, cd

I have a quick question. I need to add a cron to my debain crontab using an automated shell script and I need the cron to do two things:

1. cd into /etc/application
2. run the command "scrapy crawl"

> crontab -l | { /bin/cat; /bin/echo "* 3 * * * cd /etc/application"; }
>   | crontab -

How do I get it to also run the scrapy crawl command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have multiple commands in a single crontab line. Just separate them with semicolons:

```
crontab -l | { /bin/cat; /bin/echo "* 3 * * * cd /etc/application ; scrapy crawl"; } | crontab -
```