# Cron job for backup a database to github

Tags: mysql, git, macos, cron

I created a cron job to create a dump of my mysql database and add it to my github repo.
But it doesn’t push it to the master it works until the commit. But it doesn’t push it.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -proot1234 core > ~/dbdump/dump.sql

cd ~/dbdump
git add dump.sql
git commit -m "test"
git push origin master
```

```
*/5 * * * * /Users/Anjula/test.sh
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with the above thing?

Comment: @AnkitJindal git push origin master doesn’t work

Comment: Did you get any error? Do you have origin setup for your repo? Try running `git remote -v`

Comment: @AnkitJindal I don’t get any errors if I run ```git status``` it says that I'm ahead 1 commit origin/master

Comment: `git status` only says that your local copy is ahead by one commit. Also, look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578520/git-push-not-working-inside-a-cron-job)

Comment: Could be an auth issue? Have you set up SSH keys?

Comment: Seems you are trying to push to a repo that you don't have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I haven’t set up the ssh keys