# Python: How to handle 'crontab' command?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

We know the `crontab` command is used for scheduled tasks in Linux.

I want to write a Python script. Its function is to receive some data (these data are related to crontab setting) and execute a 'crontab' command in order to reset the content of the user's crontab file.

I know how to execute external Linux commands in Python. But when you execute the `crontab` command (e.g. `crontab -u xxx -e`), you need to interact with an editor to modify the user's crontab file. (Suppose I don't know where the file is. For new users, `crontab` will generate a new file anyway. And I don't execute the command as the `root` user).

So the question is, how can I just execute `crontab` in Python? Is there any way to avoid interacting with an editor to modify the user's crontab file in Python?

My OS is ubuntu 14.01.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1#92395 for an excellent answer to this question.

Comment: That is not what I want. I know how to execute linux commands in python. But my situation is different from that. I have re-edited my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want it in Python, you can do "something" like this:

```
import os;
...
cur_cron = os.popen('crontab -l > current_crontab.txt');
cur_cron.read();
cur_cron.close();
fopen_cron = file('current_crontab.txt', 'a');
fopen_cron.write("\n### Comment here if you like");
fopen_cron.write("\n* * * * * Put your command here");
fopen_cron.close();
```

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab).

### Installation

```
sudo -H pip install python-crontab
```

### Concepts

- A *cron* is a time-based job scheduler which is related to a user.
- A *job* has a command and a comment and is "attached" to a cron.
- A *job* is executed by the cron it is attached to at given times.

### Code examples

List system cron jobs:

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(tabfile='/etc/crontab', user=False)  # system users cron
# cron  = CronTab(user=True)  # current users cron
# cron  = CronTab(user='username')  # other users cron
for job in cron:
    print(job)
```

Create a new job:

```
job = cron.new(command='/foo/bar', comment='SomeID')
```

Enable / disable job:

```
job.enable()
job.enable(False)
```

Find an existing job by comment:

```
iter = cron.find_comment('ID or some text')
```

Remove Items::

```
cron.remove( job )
cron.remove_all('echo')
cron.remove_all(comment='foo')
cron.remove_all(time='*/2')
```

Clear entire cron of all jobs::

```
cron.remove_all()
```

Comment: How to list all existing crons (without using regex or names)?

Comment: How to modify a old job?  job.command='new-cmd'  ?

Comment: @0xc0de I'm not sure if this functionality was added after your question, but [per the documentation](https://gitlab.com/doctormo/python-crontab/), you can do something like this to get all existing jobs: `from crontabs import CronTabs; for cron in CronTabs(): print(repr(cron))`. Another alternative is: `jobs = CronTabs.all()`. All jobs are added to a `CronTab` object which can further be used as documented per the project.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only lines other than the command line that `python-crontab` allows are comment lines. You cannot add line for environment variables which are often necessary for a cron job to run successfully.

Answer (score 3):

With Vixie crontab, you could do something like this (obviously you could check for errors and so on):

```
import subprocess

cron_in = subprocess.Popen(['crontab', '-l'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cur_crontab, _ = cron_in.communicate()
# new_crontab = do_my_magic(cur_crontab)
cron_out = subprocess.Popen(['crontab', '-'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
cron_out.communicate(input=new_crontab)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could/should first dump your current crontab with `crontab -l`, edit it the way you want (e. g. add some lines, or modify) and then install the new one.

This usually works with `crontab <filename>`, but should as well work with `crontab -` and then piping the new contents into the process's stdin.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is *reset the content of user crontab file* , then just remove the crontab file (or overwrite with your default) , and reload the cron service  .