# Crontab file is not created when called

Tags: c, bash, audio, cron

I am creating a cronjob file to play an audio file in C, bash file is created but redirected output file is not created.

This is my cron job file: musicFile.txt

```
#!/bin/bash 
crontab -l >> alarmFile 
55 10 * * * XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) play -q /Users/harunsasmaz/Desktop/music.wav > alarmFile 
crontab alarmFile 
rm -f alarmFile 
rm -f musicFile.txt
```

However, `alarmFile` is not created when I run `bash musicFile.txt`

This is how I am trying to run bash file:

```
void bashTheCrontab()
{
  char *temp[100];
  char *text = "bash musicFile.txt";
  shapeCrontab(text, temp);
  execvp(temp[0], temp);
}
void shapeCrontab(char *text, char *ret[])
{
  char arr[100];
  strcpy(arr, text);
  char *token;
  int index = 0;
  token = strtok(arr, " ");
  while (token != NULL)
  {
    ret[index] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    strcpy(ret[index++], token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
}
```

I probably have some coding mistakes but I cannot figure out.

Comment: Better, unrelated: `ret[index] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);`

Comment: You might be interested in : [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)