# How can I access the crontab file with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, electron

I am currently developing an Electron app and need it to **look into the crontab file and parse it**.

How can Node.js (or something else in Electron) access the main crontab file and read it?

I looked into the cron-parser library but it is only able to read cron-formatted strings, not access the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be the crontab file? If all you are trying to do is add cron jobs programmatically, just drop a file in /etc/cron.d/ with the cron format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job

Comment: @GuilhermeLofranoCorneto I can create another cron file if needed, but what I need is to read a cron file anyway. Is it more feasible to read and parse a custom cron file than to do it with the crontab one?

Comment: The key thing here is that the crontab file isn't supposed to be read directly. If you run crontab -e repeatedly, you'll see a new tmp file will be generated each time. This temp file is just a mirror of whatever is under the current user in /var/spool/cron/crontabs, which also isn't supposed to be accessed directly. I'll write up an alternative as an answer.

Comment: Just use the `fs` module and read what ever file you want... Keep in mind that your programm need the rights to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the crontab file we see when we run is just a tmp file that shows whatever cron jobs the current user has created (which are stored in /var/spool/cron/crontabs) when whe don't normally have access to those files, I'd suggest you run a shell script to get these data:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("crontab -l", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    //Do stuff with the read string on stdout
});
```

Hopefully this should give you the contents of the crontab under the user that's running the node script